# Select data basis of two values of one column matches of a table

Tags: mysql

suppose this is my table structure of table user

```
id  field_id       user_id   value
1   1               37       Lalit
4   2               37        Test
5   13              37        123
6   18              37        324
7   28              37        english
8   33              37        203
9   21              37        201
10   1               39       Mukesh
11   2               39        Test
12   13              39        523
13   18              39        245
14   28              39        French
15   33              39        278
16   21              39        2897
```

So I wnat to get the result to match the two or three values from the column value and want the result

I made query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user where value =123 AND value=523;
```

But it is not working please give solution how we get the result

Comment: Tried using `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: Please tell me the exact requirement .

Answer (score 0):

A value in a row, as per your example, cannot be both 123 and 523. You have to use OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM user WHERE value=123 OR value=523;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also use `IN` clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
FROM user 
WHERE value IN (123, 523);
```